# Infer generic types for fields in nested object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a data object for the state of a form with nested fields, but I'm having problems with type inference for nested fields.
I've tried using unions and conditional types, but I don't fully understand how to do it correctly.

Link to TS Playground:
https://tsplay.dev/mxoJzN

```
interface IField<V> {
  value: V;
}

class Field<V> implements IField<V> {
  value: V;

  constructor(params: { value: V }) {
    this.value = params.value;
  }
}


type TFields<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends IField<T[K]> ? IField<T[K]> : TFields<T[K]> }

class Form<T> {
  fields: TFields<T>;
  
  constructor(fields: TFields<T>) {
    this.fields = fields;
  }
}

/*
Expected:
{
  id: IField<string>,
  auth: {
    login: IField<string>,
    password: IField<number>,
    code: {
      isValid: IField<boolean>
    }
  }
}

Received:
{
  id: string,
  auth: TFields<{
    login: string,
    password: number,
    code: TFields<{
      isValid: boolean
    }>
  }>
}
*/

type FormSchema = { 
  id: string,
  auth: {
    login: string,
    password: number,
    code: {
      isValid: boolean
    }
  }
}

const form = new Form<FormSchema>({
  id: new Field({ value: '' }),
  auth: {
    login: new Field({ value: '' }),
    password: new Field({ value: 0 }),
    code: {
      isValid: new Field({ value: false })
    }
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to recursively apply `TFields` for object properties, and use `IField` for the other properties, you can define `TFields` as

```
type TFields<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? TFields<T[K]> : IField<T[K]>
}
```

This will make the `form` sample correctly typed. If you have a specific set of primitive types, e.g. `number`, `string`, & `boolean`, you could also replace the `IField<T[K]>` above with `T[K] extends number | string | boolean ? IField<T[K]> : never`, so you'll get an error for unsupported types.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDFgQDYBMA8AagHzIDeAUMsgG5zYCuEAXMoQNwUC%20FFC2cAM6DkmHARLJgAWwAO2CNIjgRGLHiKlK1OoxZtOVZAgD2IQWCgMEYE1AAUsuFDjTBrMrXpNWhZFwBKciNqMAALYEEAOl0mZABeZCcXNxjvCE5qHh4KMABPWRQAFTE8QXwi0kTtZABtAGkpEGQAawg8kxhkIoBdViKGnuQIAA9IEFwREwAjACsIG2QAfm7SyYrB0lY1cQ36nuJuXn4hEXQ7aQqtIxh1Sf618srM5CNTc0trWwdb8XdVu5PYhBGqhCLRX5lBLISGTF7ZXgAegAVBQAKIjQo2CC4ZgUGrAXFoNb4CxQUAAc2IABojHAGOEPCFkNgTBTQNsSWTKTTmU5hAB3OxEnYaEAMaTTaC86jUUy4fSg2WRQj0Qmcu74aYmEwKOAgQ6y-xGBEUABKCwgwBoOLxBKJ3JAFNp1HpjIBf3wStZ7JArEdzr5pyFUCJ4sl0Bdsvl%20hKgK9zOoKrVRO1uog%20uZXEN-kOPGRiN4%20UKoguAGUEGFFHBoZ4jOrkAGo26wkyjT6OY3LJSo9R%20YIQ2GJVKoL3jCYFW2jVJBKrsA203qQFmTUc%20GYLDCLtCQBABaWoJdzoeK1XpHBiPZ7axd-u1levHpWAByZ-%20ALNhmt4Lttmd2%20iHcD6xPor7vmO-aDjee6AeIwHpKwAAM4HMjGU5Gsm85hjB96eCBrDwNgggoIEK5ZLSpG8EAA)